# How to create webservice for Quickbooks connector in existing application?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, quickbooks

I try to connect my application with QuickBooks Desktop application. I just installed QuickBooks Web Connector, and now I should install web service. But I don't understand the steps for creating Web Service.

I use IDE Intelij Idea. In context menu I found "Webservices" and I tried to generate code for Web Service (with axis 2 which is installed in OS). After many hours I found wsdl file for testing - [wsdl](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl) . But after generating I see just two files Service.asmx and services.xml. But all classes are described by http://developer.intuit.com/ namespace and methods also are used from this site. How can I implement my own methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I implement my own methods?

You can't. This isn't how the Web Connector works.

The Web Connector implements a specific set of predefined methods for authentication, sending requests, receiving responses, and handling errors.

The `sendRequestXML` method in particular is called over and over again by the Web Connector, and your job is to then return *specific XML messages from this method* that tell QuickBooks to do specific things.

For example, if your goal is to add 3 customers, add 2 invoices, and then add a payment, you would implement the `sendRequestXML` method so that the first time it's called, it returns XML to add the first customer. The second time it's called, you return XML to add the second customer. The third, the third customer XML. The fourth, the first invoice XML. Etc. etc. etc.

Usually, this is done by implementing a queue on your side from which `sendRequestXML` pulls the XML requests from.

Much bigger explanation here:

http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview#Technical_Overview_of_the_Web_Connector

Comment: Ok. I understood you. But I want to ask you about integration with my own existing application. My app is running on JBoss 5.1.0 and has many models (clients, customers etc.). How can I wire logically Web Connector with my application. I thought that after processing wsdl will appear some java classes with methods sendRequestXML and I'll can change these methods for processing my application models. But how I sad earlier I have just two files and no Java classes are created.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong place, or generating things incorrectly. .asmx files are .NET files, not Java files. What are you using to generate the classes?

Comment: "WebService for QBFS created using ASP.NET to troubleshoot QuickBooks WebConnector" now I see. But where I can found wsld file for Java? On consolibyte the link is outdated. Is there one real step-by-step example?

Comment: WSDL files are language-agnostic. You can use them in any language. But you can't generate .NET classes and expect them to work in Java... You need to use a tool which generates Java classes from WSDL.